# Is there a default shortcut for System Monitor?

Tags: shortcut-keys, system-monitor

Is there a default keyboard shortcut for opening System Monitor?

Comment: No. You can set it yourself, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a default keyboard shortcut for the System Monitor application (*gnome-system-monitor*), but you can make a custom keyboard shortcut for it. To make a custom shortcut go to *System Settings* -> *Keyboard* -> *Shortcuts* tab -> select Custom Shortcuts. To add a custom shortcut, click the **+** button at the bottom of the window. To edit a shortcut, click the row and hold down the new keys or press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to clear.

[image]

Comment: You might want to add the command to use for System Monitor.